# How to enable zooming and panning in CorePlot

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

We are currently using Coreplot but it seems that Coreplot does not support zooming and panning. How can we enable this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `allowsUserInteraction` to `YES` on the plot space to turn on the interactive features. The `allowPinchScaling` property of the hosting view controls whether the graph responds to pinch gestures. It defaults to `YES`.